# C++ pthread deadlock solution

Tags: c++, deadlock

I am trying to use p_thread to print out numbers in order like:
0
1
2
3
4
Without using a global variable, just local variable, but I met deadlock and I don't know how to fix it yet.
This is my code:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static pthread_mutex_t bsem;    // Mutex semaphore
static pthread_cond_t waitTurn = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  // Condition variable to control the turn
//static int turn; // Index to control access to the turn array
static int nthreads; // Number of threads from input


struct SFE{
    int turn;
    int thread;
};

void *thread_function(void *void_ptr_argv)
{
    SFE *threadNum = (SFE *) void_ptr_argv;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bsem);
    // if its not our turn then wait
    while(threadNum->turn != threadNum->thread){
        pthread_cond_wait(&waitTurn, &bsem);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bsem);
    
    std::cout << "I am Thread " << threadNum->turn << std::endl;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bsem);
    threadNum->turn++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&waitTurn);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bsem);
    
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::cin >> nthreads;
    pthread_mutex_init(&bsem, NULL); // Initialize bsem to 1
    pthread_t *tid= new pthread_t[nthreads];
    SFE threadNumber;
    threadNumber.turn = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<nthreads;i++)
    {
        // initialize the thread number here (remember to follow the rules from the specifications of the assignment)
        threadNumber.thread = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], nullptr, thread_function, (void*)&threadNumber);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], nullptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting a simple way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Think about `threadNum->thread`. `threadNum` is an unique object, thus each thread gets an unspecified number `threadNum->thread` between 0 and `nthreads`. Only the last thread gets the correct number `nthreads - 1` .

You should update

```
struct SFE{
    int *turn;
    int thread;
};
```

Allocate the array `SFE threadNum[nthread]` and pass `&threadNum[i]` to i-th thread.

```
int turn = 0;
for(int i=0;i<nthreads;i++)
{
    // initialize the thread number here (remember to follow the rules from the specifications of the assignment)
    threadNumber[i].turn = &turn;
    threadNumber[i].thread = i;
    pthread_create(&tid[i], nullptr, thread_function, &threadNumber[i]);
}
```

Your code is C-ism. This code w/o iostream and `new` is a clean C. If you use C++, all will be much easier.

Comment: yeah I know if you use a array of reference to pass different thread will be easy. Is there anyway to use the same address and using mutex lock to do this problem?

Comment: Use C++ threads. You can pass there copied and referenced values w/o using arrays.